# Pivot longer in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

Here is my input dataset which contains one row and 12 columns/variables:

```
df <- data.frame(q_q10=0,q_q20=0, q_q30=0,q_q40=400,
                 q_q10_low=0,q_q20_low=0,q_q30_low=0,q_q40_low=350,
                 q_q10_up=24,q_q20_up=24,q_q30_up=24,q_q40_up=500)
```

I would like to reshape df so I get a dataframe with 4 rows and 3 variables (quantiles, low, up). In other words, I'd like df2 looks like :

```
data.frame(quantile=c(0,0,0,400), low=c(0,0,0,350), up=c(24,24,24,500))
```

How can I do that with `pivot_longer()` function from the `tidyr` package?

Thanks!!

Comment: Note that `pivot_longer` is from the `tidyr` package, so I edited your question and tags. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you will have to use `tidyr`, but at the beginning you can do `setNames(as.data.frame(t(matrix(df,ncol = 3)), c("quantile","low","up")),c("q10","q20","q30","q40"))`

Answer (score 11):

You can do this in a single pivot if you rename the quantile variables, in this case we add `_quantile` to the end of each so they are identified as a set when pivoting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  rename_with(.fn = ~ paste0(.x, "_quantile"), ends_with("0")) |>
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = ".*_(.*)", names_to = ".value")

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  quantile   low    up
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1        0     0    24
2        0     0    24
3        0     0    24
4      400   350   500
```

Comment: Oh that's slick, I've never tried `NA` in the `names_to=` ... I'll have to look into that more

Comment: You actually don't need NA, `names_pattern = ".*_(.*)", names_to = ".value"` is enough, i.e. defining one group

Comment: @Mael - ah, indeed.  Originally I included the variable identifier column but made a quick edit to drop it after double checking OP's desired output. Edited.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this can be done in a single step (*edit*: since corrected with @RitcheSacramento's (lotus's?) excellent answer), so we'll double-pivot it. Not sure if you need the `qcode` (my name) column, I kept it just in case.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = everything(), names_pattern = "q_([^_]*)(_.*)?", names_to = c("qcode", "lowup")) %>%
  mutate(lowup = if_else(nzchar(lowup), sub("^_", "", lowup), "quantile")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = qcode, names_from = lowup, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#   qcode quantile   low    up
#   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 q10          0     0    24
# 2 q20          0     0    24
# 3 q30          0     0    24
# 4 q40        400   350   500
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually according to the given data why not to simply:

```
matrix(df, ncol = 3) |>
  `colnames<-`(c("quantile", "low", "up"))
```

or even in one-liner thanks to @jpsmith:

```
matrix(df, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("quantile", "low", "up")))

     quantile low up 
[1,] 0        0   24 
[2,] 0        0   24 
[3,] 0        0   24 
[4,] 400      350 500
```

Comment: Great idea! Note you could do this all in one matrix step without the need for `colnames<-`: `matrix(df, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("quantile", "low", "up")))`

Comment: @jpsmith Thnk you for your valuable input! I've edited the answer

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you will have to use tidyr, but at the beginning you can do

```
setNames(
  as.data.frame(
    matrix(df,ncol = 3),
    c("q10","q20","q30","q40")
  ),
  c("quantile","low","up")
)

    quantile low  up
q10        0   0  24
q20        0   0  24
q30        0   0  24
q40      400 350 500
```

Pasted from my 46 min ago comment, but with inversion of column and rows and without transpose (`t()`).