# Aggregate dataset by counting values across multiple specified columns in R

Tags: r, aggregate, character

My dataset contains several columns: The first column "Sex" has 2 values (M/F), the second column "Group" indicates a breed group (40 different values), and 13 columns that each represent one specific year containing information about the age at a specific year (<1-20) (Some of them contain empty values, Image 1). One line marks one individual.

[image: Image 1]

I would like to have this data aggregated into a new table that tells me how many males/females of a specific breed group of a specific age there are in the dataset (counts). The year is not relevant. Empty age-values mean that an individual was not alive at that year and should be ignored when counting. An Example of the desired outcome is shown in Image 2.

[image: Image 2]

What kind of formula is suitable here? I was thinking about the aggregate function, but as the values are not numeric, I did not find the correct formula to apply here.

Comment: Hi Elena. The current structure of your data as imported to R is unclear. You have only provided pictures, and these seem to be from a spreadsheet program rather than from R. Numeric columns in R data frames cannot be empty, but can contain `NA` values. At the moment your question is asking "how do I go from this data structure that doesn't exist in R, to this other data structure that doesn't exist in R?". As a minimum, we would need reproducible data as text. In R this can be obtained using the `dput` function. Please provide a [mre] and read about [ask] a question that folks can help with

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: This seems likely to be a combination of pivoting/reshaping (https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280929/3358272 (includes stats::reshape); (names_pattern) https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272; (multiple value columns) https://stackoverflow.com/q/61367186/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71530939/3358272; (dual-pivot?) https://stackoverflow.com/q/77316504/3358272) as well as summarize-by-group (https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple funs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Allan Cameron commented, this data structure does not exist in R. Your screenshots suggests the following: you aim to import a Excel/.csv file as shown in the first screenshot and then aim to summarize in R similarly as shown in the second screenshot. If you have the ability, a save way might be to replace the blank cells inside your first Excel/.csv file by NA, thus becoming these cells `NA` in R once you imported the file (yes, we can do it inside R, but why not adopt better practices while documenting data in Excel/.csv).

`dat` in the example below should illustrate your (imported) data and the coding below shows an approach how you could get something (tidier) like shown in your second screenshot.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  id = c(paste("id", 1:4, sep = "_")),
  sex = c("m", "m", "f", "f"),
  grp = c("grp1", "grp2", "grp4", "grp4"),
  y_2008 = c(14, 15, NA, 15),
  y_2009 = c(15, 16, 15, 16),
  y_2010 = c(16, 17, 16, 17),
  y_2011 = c(17, NA, 17, NA),
  y_2012 = c(NA, NA, 18, NA),
  y_2013 = NA
)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("y_")) %>% 
  mutate(your_count = sum(!is.na(value)), .by = c(sex, grp, value)) %>% 
  distinct(sex, grp, value, your_count) %>% 
  drop_na(value)
```