# How do I add a legend to ggplot with two scatter plots (geom_point() )

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-point

I have a table I read into R to plot with ggplots. I need to plot two sets of data points and also use an `ifelse` condition to be able to show specific genes.

I would like to show a legend to the plot, but I don't know how to get there. I tried `scale_color_manual()`, but it doesn't show the legend still.

I'm not sure where I'm wrong.

this is my command:

```
ggplot(data=combined_dataset) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = rf_bjab_prot, y = rf_bjab_trans), 
             alpha=0.7, size = 3, color = ifelse(combined_dataset$name.miapaca %in% genes, "blue1", 'maroon')) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = rf_miapaca_prot, y = rf_miapaca_trans), 
             alpha=0.2, size = 3, color = ifelse(combined_dataset$name.miapaca %in% genes, "#D55E00", 'skyblue')) +
 geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(x = rf_bjab_prot, y = rf_bjab_trans, 
                               label = ifelse(name.miapaca %in% genes, name.miapaca, "")), 
                  size = 3, box.padding = 1, color = c("darkblue") ) + 
  geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(x = rf_miapaca_prot, y = rf_miapaca_trans,
                                label = ifelse(rf_miapaca_prot >= 0.05 & rf_miapaca_trans >= 60, name.miapaca, "")),
                  size = 3, box.padding = 1, color = c("green") ) +
  geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(x = rf_bjab_prot, y = rf_bjab_trans, 
                                label = ifelse(rf_bjab_prot <= -0.5 & rf_bjab_trans <= -10, name.miapaca, '')),
                  size = 3, box.padding = 1, color = c("#009E73") )
```

whoch produces the following plot:

[image]

what do I need to change in order for the legend to be shown?

thanks
Assa

P.S.
These are the data points I'm trying to plot:

```
> genes <- c("EGFR", "REL", "IGHM", "CD79B")
> head(combined_dataset) |> select(starts_with("rf"))
  rf_miapaca_prot rf_bjab_prot rf_miapaca_trans rf_bjab_trans
1      0.14152102   0.00000000         33.06388     0.0000000
2      0.18698557   0.00000000         31.59254     0.0000000
3      0.47772063   0.01919795          0.00000     0.0000000
4      0.19858826   0.33263854         59.22759    -0.2085603
5      0.09897121   0.00000000         32.50715     0.0000000
6      0.16365261   0.00000000          0.00000     0.0000000
```

Also running this code doesn't provide a legend

```
ggplot(data=combined_dataset) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = rf_bjab_prot, y = rf_bjab_trans), 
             alpha=0.7, size = 3, color = "blue1") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = rf_miapaca_prot, y = rf_miapaca_trans), 
             alpha=0.2, size = 3, color =  "#D55E00")
```

Comment: `'genes' not found`

Comment: I don't think it is important, but I added the gene vector to the example. Though I don't get a legend also if the `ifelse` clause is not stated. I can modify the plot to have no if clause, and still I don't see any legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way with `ggplot2` is generally to pivot the data so that you can do a single call to `geom_point()`. To aid in this, I'll generate a helper frame that maps each "type" with the color and alpha you want.

```r
my_scales <- data.frame(type = c("rf_bjab", "rf_miapaca"), color = c("blue1", "#D55E00"), alpha = c(0.7, 0.2))
my_scales
#         type   color alpha
# 1    rf_bjab   blue1   0.7
# 2 rf_miapaca #D55E00   0.2

longer <- tidyr::pivot_longer(
  combined_dataset, cols = everything(),
  names_pattern = "(.*)_(prot|trans)", names_to = c("type", ".value"))
longer
# # A tibble: 12 × 3
#    type         prot  trans
#    <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 rf_miapaca 0.142  33.1  
#  2 rf_bjab    0       0    
#  3 rf_miapaca 0.187  31.6  
#  4 rf_bjab    0       0    
#  5 rf_miapaca 0.478   0    
#  6 rf_bjab    0.0192  0    
#  7 rf_miapaca 0.199  59.2  
#  8 rf_bjab    0.333  -0.209
#  9 rf_miapaca 0.0990 32.5  
# 10 rf_bjab    0       0    
# 11 rf_miapaca 0.164   0    
# 12 rf_bjab    0       0    

ggplot(longer, aes(prot, trans)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = type, alpha = type)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(my_scales$color, my_scales$type)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = setNames(my_scales$alpha, my_scales$type))
```

[image: ggplot scatterplot, two colors, with a legend labeling the two colors and alphas]

Sometimes pivoting/reshaping is not possible or you just want a quick "hack", for those times you can do something like this:

```r
ggplot(combined_dataset) +
  geom_point(aes(rf_bjab_prot, rf_bjab_trans, color = "rf_bjab", alpha = "rf_bjab")) +
  geom_point(aes(rf_miapaca_prot, rf_miapaca_trans, color = "rf_miapaca", alpha = "rf_miapaca")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(my_scales$color, my_scales$type)) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values = setNames(my_scales$alpha, my_scales$type))
```

[image: same ggplot scatterplot, now one legend for each of color and alpha]

It's likely possible to combine the two legends into one so that the dots reflect both the `color=` and `alpha=` at the same time, but I think in general the first method is preferred and easier to scale to larger data.

---

Reshaping/pivoting the data from wide to long seem simple here but can be more difficult if you have other columns (that should not pivot) and aren't familiar with the functions. Here are a bunch of Q/As on SO that talk about the topic with workable code, using `tidyr::pivot_*`, `reshape2::melt`, and even `base::reshape`: [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272), [how to use pivot_longer in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280929/3358272) (includes stats::reshape); (names_pattern) [Transforming wide data to long format with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272;) (multiple value columns) [pivot_longer into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61367186/3358272), [Is there way to pivot_longer to multiple values columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71530939/3358272;) (dual-pivot?) [Pivot longer in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77316504/3358272)

Comment: Thanks for a really great and very elaborate answer. I now understand R and the structure of ggplot2 a bit better. Unfortunately, as I show in my example, I have more then just one color per sample, as I also add the `ifelse` clause (This is also why I didn't pivoted the table, as I need the names column). When I test the example you show I get the warning `No shared levels found between names(values) of the manual scale and the data's colour values.` and no legend appers (which makes sense). But I don't know how I can add the levels if using an if clause. any advice? thx

Comment: I decided to accept your answer, as it leads me to the desired plot. I have just modified the table with the colours to have enough rows for each of my conditions. In my case it were three. `my_scales <- data.frame(type = c("significant genes", "bjab sample", "miapaca sample"), color = c("blue1", "maroon", "#D55E00"), alpha = c(0.7, 0.7, 0.2))`

Comment: That was expected: since I know nothing about the rest of your data, how could I know to include `"significant genes"` or know how you wanted the other two labeled?