# Facing problem with gather() function in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, tidyr

I've a .txt file which has 56 columns. The dataset with multiple columns where each column represents a different sample, and I want to reshape this dataset from wide to long format using the gather() function from the tidyr package in R. However, after applying gather(), all samples are assigned the same name in the "samples" column.

My code:

```
data %>%
 gather(key="samples",value="counts",-Gene) %>%
 head()
```

Why am i getting same name for every sample? How to fix it? Thank you so much

I expected each sample to have its own distinct name in the "samples" column after reshaping the data. Specifically, I thought that each column name representing a sample in the original dataset would be represented as a unique value in the "samples" column.

However, after applying gather(), all samples were assigned the same name "CKC1" in the "samples" column. This was unexpected and not the desired outcome. I expected to see distinct sample names corresponding to the original column names, but this did not happen.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Goodday! Up front, `gather` has been soft-deprecated ("superseded") for years, as shown in `?gather`. I encourage you to switch to using `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Given that ... questions on SO do much better if they are reproducible. This means including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Until then, here are some relevant links about reshaping data from "wide" to "long" formats: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280929/3358272 (includes stats::reshape); (names_pattern) https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272; (multiple value columns) https://stackoverflow.com/q/61367186/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71530939/3358272; (dual-pivot?) https://stackoverflow.com/q/77316504/3358272

Comment: If `data` has six or more rows, then the code you provided (b/c of `head()`) will only show one sample, since the others will appear beyond row 6 of the output. Remove the `%>% head()` part if you want to see all the reshaped data, which presumably includes other samples if you look further.

Comment: e.g. compare `data <- data.frame(Gene = "A", CKC1 = 1:10, CKNY = 101:110); data |> gather(key = "samples", value = "counts", -Gene) |> head()` with and without the `|> head()` part.   (FYI `|>` is the "base pipe" and is generally interchangeable with `%>%`). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe

Comment: The updated equivalent for `gather()` is  `pivot_longer()` which is pretty much a drop-in replacement with different argument names. `data |> pivot_longer(-Gene, names_to = "samples", values_to = "counts")`. One major difference for your use case is that `pivot_longer` will show the data in order starting with its original row (e.g. all the columns from row 1 first, instead of all the rows from column 1 first like with `gather()`) , so you presumably won't see the same issue with samples looking uniform.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.